# Xldr and xlutils overriding my .xls files

Tags: python, excel

So I'm pretty new to Python programming. I'm trying to write this program, that opens all .xls and .xlsx files within the same directory and instantly saves them without any changes. (My Excel files are connected and I just want to save myself the hassle of manually opening each one of them to update the interconnected values.) For this purpose, I used openpyxl library for .xlsx files and xlrd + xlutils for older .xls files. Everything works just fine with openpyxl, but when I open .xls files with xlrd, it replaces all the formulas with actual numbers, so it breaks the connections between the files. If someone could help me solve this problem, I would really appreciate it...

```
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl as xl
import xlrd
from xlutils.save import save


path = Path()

for file in path.glob('*.xlsx'):
    wb = xl.load_workbook(file)
    wb.save(file)

for file in path.glob('*.xls'):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename=file.name, formatting_info=True)                         
    save(wb, file)
```

Comment: _(My Excel files are connected and I just want to save myself the hassle of manually opening each one of them to update the interconnected values.)_ Will using openpyxl do that?

Comment: Openpyxl works just fine. I can’t use it for .xls files tho

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't have expected openpyxl to refresh/update the values like that. I'll take another look at the docs.